# How to locate the line of "Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line ..."?

Tags: errors, unicode

In my report.log I have plenty of these messages:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count405
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 35 replaced by U+FFFD.
\decimalpart=\count406
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 79 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 79 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 83 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 86 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 102 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 114 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 120 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 125 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 147 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 147 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 147 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 182 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 182 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 182 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 183 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 184 replaced by U+FFFD.
```

Unfortunately, the line number mentioned does not correspond to something in my `report.tex` file. How can I properly locate these errors?

Here my `.latexmkrc`:

```
system ("mkdir -p build/figures");

@default_files = ('report.tex');
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo gls 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'glo');

# Custom dependency and function for nomencl package
  add_cus_dep( 'nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls' );
  sub makenlo2nls {
  system( "makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \"$_[0].nls\" \"$_[0].nlo\"" );
}

$out_dir = 'build';
$pdflatex = 'xelatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape';
$latex = 'latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape';
```

Comment: If that is a full log and you have not omitted any lines, the line numbers relate to `(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex` which is.. odd

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log fragment

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count405
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 35 replaced by U+FFFD.
```

You see that `(` as `xstring.sty` was opened then  `(` as `xstring.tex` was opened, as there are no `)` any line numbers in error messages relate to  `xstring.tex` as the most recent file on the stack of currently open files.

That file does have non-ascii comments but in its current version (in texlive 2022 at least) it is correctly encoded as UTF-8 and starts:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% Ce fichier contient le code de l'extension "xstring"
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                    %
\def\xstringname               {xstring}                             %
\def\xstringversion              {1.84}                              %
%                                                                    %
\def\xstringdate              {2021/07/21}                           %
```

and line 35 where you see the first error is:

```
\newcount\decimalpart% compteurs utilisés par xstring
```

with a UTF-8 e-acute in a comment